# Necessary Condition for Prime Ideal in Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> If $P$ is an ideal in a ring $R$ such that $P \neq R$ and (1) for all $a,b \in R$ with $ab \in P$ implies $a \in P$ or $b \in P$, then $P$ is prime. Conversely if $P$ is prime and R is commutative, then P satisfies condition (1)

The forward implication was easy to prove. However, I am having trouble with the converse, and Hungerford's explanation doesn't seem to be helping. Here is a quote:

> "If $R$ is commutative, this implies that $(a)(b) \subseteq (ab)$, whence $(a)(b) \subseteq P$. If $P$ is prime, then either $(a) \subseteq P$ or $(b) \subseteq P$, whence $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.

Note that $(a) = \{ra + na \mid r \in R, n \in \Bbb{Z} \}$  is the ideal generated by $a$. So I agree that $(a)(b) \subseteq (ab)$, and therefore $(a)(b) \subseteq P$. I also agree that this implies $(a) \subseteq P$ or $(b) \subseteq P$, since $P$ is a prime ideal and $(a)$ and $(b)$ are ideals. But I don't see how we can conclude from this that either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. Specifically, I don't see how $a \in (a)$ and $b \in (b)$ can be true if $R$ isn't assumed to be unital.

Comment: What is $(1)$ exactly?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry about that. Should be fixed.

Comment: What's your definition of $(a)$ ? (Moreover in these questions you usually have $R$ unital)

Comment: @Max If $a$ is in the center of $R$, which is always the case if $R$ is commutative, then $(a)$ takes the form $\{ra + na \mid r \in R, n \in \Bbb{Z} \}$. Hungerford never implicitly assumes a ring is unital.

Comment: What happens in the definition of $(a)$ if you let $r=0$ and $n=1?$

Comment: Since $(a)$ is the ideal generated by $a$, then $a\in (a)$ by definition, because $(a)$ is the intersection of all ideals containing $a$.

Comment: @user193319 - It's not stupidity, it's an oversight. We all have these moments, more often than many would like to believe. I used to tell my students that the only stupid question is the one you don't ask. Asking questions is how we learn.

Comment: @user193319 If you like, you should post the answer you learned as a solution to your question. It's better than leaving the question without any answers, and is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: I think my comment answered the question as asked so I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (a) is the ideal generated by a, then a∈(a) by definition, because (a) is the intersection of all ideals containing a.